# How to Compare one row with other rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set that consist of team members.

I want to calculate the Average of only member 2.

However, there are conditions for the calculation to meet like,

for example, id 1 have Anna and Sam working together, I want to calculate only for member2 which is Sam

For that, I want to sum the score of the ID's that have

- Sam working with him self like `id:2 member1:Sam  member2:Sam`
- Sam working with other member but not Anna(member1) like `id:3 member1:Sam  member2:Nihal` OR `id:4 member1:Nihal  member2:Sam`

Then divide by distinct #ID

### Input

```
+----+---------+---------+-------+
| ID | member1 | member2 | score |
+----+---------+---------+-------+
|  1 | Anna    | Sam     |    10 |
|  2 | Sam     | Sam     |    30 |
|  3 | Sam     | Nihal   |    40 |
|  4 | Nihal   | Sam     |    50 |
|  5 | Sam     | Anna    |    20 |
|  6 | Anna    | Anna    |    60 |
|  7 | Nihal   | May     |    70 |
|  8 | May     | May     |    80 |
+----+---------+---------+-------+
```

### Output

```
+----+---------+---------+-------+-----+
| ID | member1 | member2 | score | AVG |
+----+---------+---------+-------+-----+
|  1 | Anna    | Sam     |    10 |  40 |-->AVG= 30+40+50/3
|  2 | Sam     | Sam     |    30 |  30 |-->AVG= score
|  3 | Sam     | Nihal   |    40 |  70 |-->AVG= 70/1
|  4 | Nihal   | Sam     |    50 |  20 |-->AVG= 30+10+20/3
|  5 | Sam     | Anna    |    20 |  60 |-->AVG= 60/1
|  6 | Anna    | Anna    |    60 |  60 |-->AVG= score
|  7 | Nihal   | May     |    70 |  80 |-->AVG= 80/1
|  8 | May     | May     |    80 |  80 |-->AVG= score
+----+---------+---------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: I don't understand your data.Can you please explain it? For example, why does sam's average change? It was 40 at ID 1, then 30 at ID 2, and then 20 at ID3. `(10+30+50) / 3` is 30, whatever order you put the additions in.

Comment: Agree with the first comment - your notes don't make sense mathematically. For example, why is Sam's average calculation different in row 1 than it is in rows 2 and 4?

Comment: If I understand, what he is trying to do is: For each line, calculate the average score of member2 for everyone they've worked for except member1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select t1.*,q.avg_score
from yourtable t1
cross apply
(
    select avg(score) as avg_score
    from yourtable t2
    where 
        t1.member2 in (t2.member1,t2.member2)
        and t1.member1 not in  (t2.member1,t2.member2)
)q
```